# What do I need to start playing Call of Cthulhu 3rd edition?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu

I'm new to the Call of Cthulhu games and I have been recently looking at all the editions for the games. For some reason the 2nd/3rd caught my eye particularly because of the retro look of it and I was wondering what exactly I needed to get to play the game besides the box set?

Comment: @ZeissIkon See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the age of the 3rd edition (1986 release date), it's unlikely that you'll find dice in the box.

So, you're going to need some dice!

In RPGs, dice are described with an "NdX" notation, where N is the number of dice and X is the number of sides. So, d6s are the standard six-sided-cubes you're probably most familiar with and d10s are 10-sided dice and 2d6 means a pair of six-sided dice. Here is what you'll most commonly need:

- 2d10 or d100 (also known as d%). Call of Cthulhu uses a percentile system, so you'll need two different d10s to generate numbers between 1 and 100. Most sets of RPG dice include one marked 10, 20, 30... and one marked 1, 2, 3... to facilitate these kinds of rolls
- 3d6 or more. Call of Cthulhu also uses six-siders, so you'll want a few of these handy as well
- Most of the rest of the standard roleplaying dice set - the d4, d8, d12, and d20 - these are used for damage rolls and sanity loss.

RPG dice are commonly sold in packs or sets which will contain everything you technically require - but a few extra d6s won't hurt.

You will also need something to write with - preferably pencils, and either some paper or some printed character sheets.

Besides that, you really don't **need** much.

You will **want** some notecards, and snacks, and a good surface or container for rolling those dice.

Comment: CoC actually requires the full suite of polyhedral dice. They're used rarely, but they come up for sanity loss and for weapon damage.

Comment: @fectin - you're right! Fixed.

Comment: Note that since the d6 is the most common dice, some people just use 2d for 2d6,  3d for 3d6 etc.